# Why conversion function is not used for an object when it is assigned to?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, language-lawyer, assignment-operator, explicit

I learned that we could provide conversion operators for our classes in C++. So I expected that for the following program, `c=1;` would've used the conversion operator `int()`. But to my surprise; that doesn't happen and we get a compiler error saying that

`error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'C' and 'int')`.

So I want to know why isn't the conversion operator used here.

```cpp
struct C {
    explicit C(int);
    operator int&(); 
};

int main() {
    C c({});
    c = 1;   //this gives error. Why the conversion operator int&() is not used here?
}
```

Note that I know that I can solve the error if I just remove the `explicit` keyword from the constructor. But my question is about why the conversion operator is not used.

I thought that since we have a conversion operator for our class, the class object can be converted to an `int` so that it can be assigned to.

Comment: The conversion operator goes the other way: `int i = c;`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I want to know why it doesn't go other way here. I mean `c` can be converted to an int here.

Comment: Because C++ doesn't work this way.  `c = 1` does not "convert to an int". After all is said and done, you still have a `C` remaining, and not an int. C++ has rules for everything. If you want it to work this way, that's what `operator=` is for. `operator=` is for assigning ***to*** an instance of a class. A conversion operator is for assigning ***from*** an instance of a class.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I want to know that since we have a conversion operator for our class so our class object can be converted to an int so that it can be assigned to.

Comment: If you want to convert an instance of the class to an `int`, then define `operator int()`, and then `int d=c` will work. Those are your options. That's the only way that C++ works.

Comment: @Sam *I learnt that we can provide conversion operators for our classes in C++* -- This is an opinion-based comment, but you learned one of the most bug-prone aspects of C++.  For a non-trivial program, can you tell when or where the conversion operator will be used?  I bet not -- code that you didn't expect being invoked all of a sudden is invoked.  That's why the standard library hardly uses this.  For example`c_str()` and not overloading `const char *` is done for `std::string`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry I recently started learning C++ and read about conversion to bool that some classes provide in standard library. So I tried writing my own program to learn more about it after reading about it in C++ Primer. I didn't see anything opinion based in that comment of mine.

Comment: @Sam -- I suggest to use conversion operators sparingly.  Don't have your entire codebase rely on these silent conversions -- take it from me, it can lead to very hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: @Sam: "*I didn't see anything opinion based in that comment of mine.*" He's saying that *his own* comment is opinion based.

Comment: There is an 'ingoing' and 'outgoing' conversion. Ingoing is implemented by the non-explicit constructor with exactly one argument, outgoing is implemented with an `operator Type()` member function. If you convert from your class `A` to your class `B` you can use either of those conversion function mechanisms (put into the respective correct class of those two). As in the example you want to convert from the built-in `int` only the constructor solution works.

Answer (score 13):

> I thought that since we have a conversion operator for our class, the class object can be converted to an int so that it can be assigned to.

Because the user-defined conversions are not considered for the left hand operand of built-in assignment operator. This can be seen from [Operators in expression's documentation](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.match.oper#4):

> For the built-in assignment operators, conversions of the left operand are restricted as follows:
>
> - no temporaries are introduced to hold the left operand, and
> - **no user-defined conversions are applied to the left operand to achieve a type match with the left-most parameter of a built-in candidate.**

(emphasis mine)

This means that the program is **ill-formed**.

Comment: "`x = y` always means `x.operator=(y)` if x is has a class type" is the clearest way I've seen this said

Comment: @Artyer Yup for a layman that should be good enough. Only if C++ was that simple(or had that simple wording).

Answer (score 4):

For the formal explanation refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76092641). I'll try to provide an intuition for why this does not work the way you expected.
In your question, you try to work out the following expression

```
c = 1;
```

where `c` is an instance of `class C`. We can make two ways of working this out.

- Making an assignment operator accepting argument of type `int`
- Making an implicit constructor accepting `int`.

So if we work with the expression mentioned, above should be sufficient.

However, one might want to write something like this.

```
int i = c; // again, c is instance of C
```

We also (if we try to think how a language designer might have thought) need to work this out. So the designers for this purpose decided to make a conversion operator which is especially for cases like this.

In summary

- If we want to make `A` from `B`, we define a constructor of `A` which accepts `B`
- If we also want to get `B` from `A`(and we can't or don't want to define a constructor of `B` which accepts `A`), we make a conversion operator which converts `A` to `B` as we wish.